# Efficiently Labeling Variable Values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with variables that are coded as integers, which I'd like to replace with their actual value labels.

For example, say I have the following dataframe:

```
>>> df=pd.DataFrame([[1,3],[2,2],[3,2]], columns=['Q1','Q2'])
>>> df
   Q1  Q2
0   1   3
1   2   2
2   3   2
```

IF, the numbers 1,2,3 represented the same value in both columns, I would have a dictionary that looked something like this:

```
labels={1:'Yes',2:'No',3:'Unsure'}
```

And I could easily recode it with applymap:

```
>>> df.applymap(labels.get)
       Q1      Q2
0     Yes  Unsure
1      No      No
2  Unsure      No
```

However, say that the integers code to a different label in each column. For example, my dictionary of value labels may look like this:

```
labels2={'Q1':{1:'Yes',2:'No',3:'Unsure'},
         'Q2':{1:'Very', 2:'A Little', 3:'Not at all'}}
```

What is the most efficient way of recoding the values in this scenario?

I could do it using apply and a for loop (see below), but it is pretty clunky. Is there a better way?

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> dfs=[]
>>> for Question in labels2:
...     d=df[Question].map(labels2[Question].get)
...     dfs.append(d)
... 
>>> pd.concat(dfs,1)
       Q1          Q2
0     Yes  Not at all
1      No    A Little
2  Unsure    A Little
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `apply` and use the column's `name` attribute to get the key for the outer dictionary:

```
>>> df.apply(lambda col: col.map(labels2[col.name]))
      Q1          Q2
0     Yes  Not at all
1      No    A Little
2  Unsure    A Little
```